# How is this instruction calculating jump destination?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I am trying to understand what this line is doing

```
   0x0000000000400f7e <+59>:    jmpq   *0x401be0(,%rax,8)
```

Let us assume $rax = 2. So we have *0x401be0+(8*2).

*0x401be0 points to 4198277. So we have 4198277+16 = 4198293 or 0x400F95.

So I am expecting the code to jump to instruction at 0x400F95. But it jumps to 0x400fc9. What is actually happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code reads a 64-bit value (a code address) from the data at address `0x401be0+8*rax` and jumps to the address read.